# Select earliest of two nullable datetimes

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

In a table with two nullable date/datetime columns, how would you efficiently select the earliest of both dates that's not NULL?

Concretely, this is what I'm interested in:

```
|   Date1    |   Date2    |    |  Expected  |
|------------|------------|    |------------|
| 2014-02-23 | 2014-01-16 |    | 2014-01-16 |
| 2014-02-01 |    NULL    |    | 2014-02-01 |
|    NULL    | 2014-01-13 |    | 2014-01-13 |
|    NULL    |    NULL    |    |    NULL    |
```

I can manage to fetch those results using either of the queries below. Both my solutions use the `LEAST` operator, which returns NULL when either of the arguments is NULL (and not just when both are NULL), so it takes some more logic to get the job done.

```
SELECT IF(ISNULL(Date1), Date2, IFNULL(LEAST(Date1, Date2), Date1)) AS EarlyDate FROM MyTable
```

or the equivalent:

```
SELECT IFNULL(IFNULL(LEAST(Date1, Date2), Date1), Date2) AS EarlyDate FROM MyTable
```

My feeling is that there's something redundant in both of my queries above. Could anyone suggest a better solution?

Comment: Seems OK to me. But see COALESCE()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to check for NULLs, try this:

```
SELECT IF(Date1 IS NULL OR Date2 IS NULL, 
          COALESCE(DATE1, DATE2), 
          LEAST(DATE1, DATE2)
       ) AS EarlyDate 
FROM MyTable
```

Working Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7940c/1

Answer (score 2):

You can use LEAST on COALESCE(date1,date2) and COALESCE(date2,date1):

```
SELECT LEAST( COALESCE(Date1,Date2) , COALESCE(Date2,Date1) ) AS EarlyDate
FROM MyTable;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN DATE1 IS NULL OR DATE2 IS NULL THEN COALESCE(DATE1,DATE2) ELSE LEAST(Date1,Date2) END AS LEAST FROM TableName
```

Result:

```
DATE
2014-01-16
2014-02-01
2014-01-13
NULL
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8ca4c/8).

**Explanation:**

If one of the dates are `NULL`, then `COALESCE()` is used to select the first non-NULL value. If both are `NOT NULL`, then `LEAST()` is used to select the least date from both.

`LEAST()` returns the least of the list of one or more expressions. Read more [**here**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least).

`COALESCE()` returns the first non-NULL value in the list, or NULL if there are no non-NULL values. Read more [**here**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce).

Comment: Will not work if a slight data change is made, like this: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8b2c8/1

Comment: @AzizShaikh: What is wrong with the example you have given. That what COALESCE() is supposed to do, right?

Comment: First row is '2014-01-16' in the 'expected result' posted in the question. However, http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8b2c8/1 gives '2014-01-23' as output.

Comment: @AzizShaikh: That is because the field has value `2014-01-23`. Check your example.

Comment: @Raging Bull: Your select statement does not return the earliest date. In case date1 is earlier than date2, your statement still returns date2, when it should return date1.